# Error "Unable to evaluate the expression"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a problem with a debugging tools named as memory.I am opening this tool *Debug tool → Windows → Memory → Memory 1*.

This is my whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSharpCompleteTutorial
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate decimal Hesaplama(int adet);
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hesaplama del = Fiyat;
        del += KDVFiyat;
        MessageBox.Show(del.Invoke(5).ToString());
    }

    public decimal Fiyat(int sayi)
    {
        return sayi * 10.5m;
    }

    public decimal KDVFiyat(int sayi)
    {
        decimal kdvharicfiyat = sayi * 10.5m;

        return kdvharicfiyat + kdvharicfiyat * 0.18m;
    }
}
}
```

I have to use simply memory tool.But it makes me an error as in the image.

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 1):

The error messages means that the memory address doesn't recognize and evaluate the expression. My suggestion is that you could get the address using the Disassembly window, and input the address in your memory window.

[image]